# Code inside subscribe is executed multiple times

Tags: angular

I'm using ng-zorro components in my project, and I want to show a model that calls a service to delete an entry, this is how I defined the delete confirm dialog :

```
  showDeleteConfirm(id: string): void{
    this.modal.confirm({
      nzTitle: 'Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer ce enregistrement ?',
      nzOnOk: () => {
          this.service.delete(id).subscribe(data => {
          this.notification.create("success", "Suppression", "L'enregistrement a été supprimée !");
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

But I had this issue where the code inside the subscribe function is executed multiple times.

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

This is my delete function :

```
delete(id: string): any{
  return this.http.delete<Entity>(this._apiURL + id, this.httpOptions).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
  let errorMessage = '';
  if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    errorMessage = `An error occurred: ${err.error.message}`;
  } else {
    errorMessage = `Server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message}`;
  }
  return errorMessage;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code of your `delete` function.

Comment: @Batajus please check my edit

Comment: Is it possible that your subscription is called twice every time?

Comment: @Batajus when I debug that code showDeleteConfirm function is only called once, but the code inside subscribe function is called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

In case you would like to make sure that code inside subscribe is executed once, you can use `take(1)` or `first()`

Example:

```
this.service.take(1).subscribe(...);
```

Also, the best practice is always to use `takeUntil()` and destroy it for example in `ngOnDestroy`

```
class myComponent {
  private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  constructor(
    private service: Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service
      .takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      .subscribe(...);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }
}
```